# Determine if a shape is closed

Tags: algorithm, shapes

[image]

Hello there,

I'm trying to find a way (an algorithm) to determine wether if a shape is closed or not, and what is the biggest closed shape.
In the above exemple, I would like to get the total surface of the 2 shapes of the left (not only one), put exclude the bottom starting figure.

I though of running through each dot (each line of the figure is determined by 2 dots ;) ), but I have trouble when it comes to "not going twice through a point I've already met".

So, i'm open to every idea...

Edit : I've put up a more complete image.

I work on a classic x,y plan. Each shape is made of linked dots. The top-right little shape is here to show that shapes can be linked, or not.

A dot is made of two x and y coords.
All dots are saved in a single table, lets call it Dots map[]. I would like to find a way to go through map[] and to get all closed shapes.

Hope it makes it more clear...

Comment: How is this shape stored?  What kind of object is it?  If it's a graph like object (connected nodes), there is a simple solution to it

Comment: All you need is a [DCEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list).

Comment: The shape is a table of Dots(x,y), so its basically connected nodes, yep. Would love to hear your solution !

Comment: How would a DCEL work as I'm not working with lines, but with dots ? :p

Answer (score 1):

I think that first you should trim the loose ends, so if a line is connected at only one end, remove it

Then choose a point with the lowest y or x coordinate and start iterating sides that have the widest angle. This is a little hard to explain given the statement of the problem.

Anyway if you have only one figure after this you should find the biggest closed shape. If you have multiple disjoint figures you need to run the algorithm multiple times.

For further help you should spell the problem in a clear statement, how is the input, what are the restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the share, just added some infos.